# Not able to trigger function from event

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, ethereum, metamask

I am not a skilled react programmer but still hope someone would care to explain what I am missing:

**What I want**
I would like to change accounts in Metamask, detect the "accountsChanged" event, and trigger the testFunction.

**What works**
I am able to trigger the testFunction by clicking the test function button.
I can detect account change (for some reason it is detected around 5 times every time I change).

**What does not work**
I am not able to trigger the testFunction upon account change and get the message `TypeError: this.testFunction is not a function`

Suspect there is something fundamental about react I am missing here...Thanks for all replies!

```
class App extends Component {
   ...
   componentDidMount = async () => {
      ...
   };

   testFunction = async =>{
      console.log("triggered the test function");
   };

   render() {
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
      console.log("account change detected");
      this.testFunction(); --> this is not working
    });

     return (
         <div className="App">
           <button type="button" onClick={this.testFunction}>test function</button>
         </div>
       );
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please try the `window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accounts => {`

Comment: Thanks @RajdeepDebnath, that actually worked! 1) Any idea why Metamask and other propose the format I used originally? See here: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/accessing-accounts.html 2) The event and function call is happening 5 times in a burst - any idea why this is? Have I placed the functions in the right place?

Comment: Please put this function `window.ethereum.on(` in `componentDidMount` not inside render

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your normal function to arrow function. Because normal function derives `this` from the object which is calling it, but arrow function derives it's `this` from surrounding scope, hence in arrow function `this` will point to your class and will have access to the methods.

```
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accounts => {
```

Also, you can continue using normal function, but in that case you can store the `this` in some other variable like `that' or 'self` and use it inside the normal function to call the methods of the class.

```
let that = this;
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function(accounts){
 that.testFunction() //this will work
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to update the component of my app when an account was changed using MetaMask. What I did was what Vivek suggested: create a reference of `this` and then handle the callback. At the end my function using etherjs and the same event of metamask (ethereun.on('accountsChanged'..was this

```
const here = this
 provider.provider.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
      console.log('Account changed!!')
      here.currentAccount = accounts[0]
})
```

This code also work with Vue